# How to remove certain statement from a function conditionally

Tags: python, function

So let's say I have a function of

```
def question():
    print("")
    question_section = str("B" + str(quiz_nmbr + 1))
    print("Question", str(quiz_nmbr) + ": " + str(sheet[question_section].value))
    question_become = str(input("Type your question: "))
    sheet[question_section].value = question_become 
    book.save('Quiz_Problems.xlsx')
```

Then let's say one time I wanted to call the `question()` function again.

However, I don't want `print("Question", str(quiz_nmbr) + ": " + str(sheet[question_section].value))` to be printed.

Is there anyway to just remove that statement for certain condition? and by condition what I mean is let's say I wanted to call the function in if else statement (which condition matters to give different output)

Comment: Do you know how to pass parameters to functions? Are you familiar with conditional expressions? Once you know these things you'll have your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def question(prompt):
    print("")
    question_section = str("B" + str(quiz_nmbr + 1))
    if prompt:
        print("Question", str(quiz_nmbr) + ": " + str(sheet[question_section].value))
    question_become = str(input("Type your question: "))
    sheet[question_section].value = question_become 
    book.save('Quiz_Problems.xlsx')
```

Then, inside your if/else clause, you can call `question(True)` or `question(False)` as desired.